# How img overflow div

Tags: css, reactjs, carousel

I'm building carousel with react, and content images are horizontally aligned.
If I say 3  tags are in div with width 1200px, how can I control these images what I want whether it's overflow container div or not?  ( cf. It's not important, however I'm using React.js)

---

sorry for skipping my codes so far. I'm trying to handle this with styled-components"

```
 const SliderContainer = styled.div`
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
`;
 const Slider = styled.div`
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: flex;
`

const IMG = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
`;

export const Slide: SFC<{
  src?: string,
  alt?: string
}> =({
  src,
  alt
}) => {
  return(
    <IMG src={src} alt={alt}/>
  )
}

export const Carousel: FC = () => {
return(
  <SliderContainer>
    <Slider>
      <Slide src={"1.png"}/>
      <Slide src={"2.png"}/>
      <Slide src={"3.png"}/>
    </Slider>
  </SliderContainer>
)
```

Comment: We need a lil more of your code ... What have you done so far ? You want to make it with css or js or even reactjs ?

Comment: @Nico I edited my question thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
     <img id="img1" />
     <img id="img2" />
     <img id="img3" /> 
  </div>
</div>
```

when we want those images( or contents) in `div` which has *container* as a classname over flow  `<div class="parent"></div>`
we should specify the length of `<div class="container"></div>`

so in this case

```
 .parent{
    width: 100%;
    overflow;
  }
  .container{
    display: flex; // so we have 3 images horizontally
    width: 1028px; // whatever but  more than .parent widh 
   } 
  .img{
    width:100%;
    height: auto; 
  }
```

the reason we should specify `.container` div width is,  we have flex display in this case, so whole img width might be auto resize through this flex properties.

and  `.parent`'s `overflow: hidden` property only make sense when it's child tag has large length more than itself.